# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'observation'

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I am trying to make encoding to run my model. Here the codes I have run and the error:

There are two columns that I want to convert. (Date and CountryID)

```
df["ID"] = pd.get_dummies(df.CountryID, prefix='CountryID')
df["Date"] = pd.get_dummies(df.Date, prefix='Date')
y=df.IndustrialP
X=df.drop('IndustrialP', axis=1)
split = int(len(df)*0.8)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:split], X[split:], y[:split], y[split:]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=10)
```

and I am getting the following error (DE is Germany's code here, which is observation under CountryID column)

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'DE'`

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Which statement is producing the error?

Comment: the last line producing the error, others worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to drop `CountyID` from the dataframe that you will use to fit the model.  You probably also want to drop `Date` as well since you are generating dummies for that.  (`Date` might not cause an error if it is included, since a date will probably silently convert to a number; but since you are using dummies for the date I presume you don't want the date itself to be a variable in the model.)

I'm a bit puzzled why you aren't getting errors from these statements:

```py
df["ID"] = pd.get_dummies(df.CountryID, prefix='CountryID')
df["Date"] = pd.get_dummies(df.Date, prefix='Date')
```

`get_dummies()` produces a DataFrame.  Assigning that into a single column of another DataFrame shouldn't work.  I got an error when I tried to do it with simple dummy data.

My best guess is that you are working with test data that actually only has one value in each of these columns. This would cause `get_dummies()` to return a single-column DataFrame, in which case the assignment should work.

If that's the case, this logic won't work when you use data that has more unique values.  I think you want to concatenate the dummy dataframes onto the original (or onto `X`).